# unable to restore stash when changes are present on your branch github desktop

Tags: github, git-stash, github-desktop

I am using Github desktop.

I was working on a project on my PC, when my teammate do some changes from his PC on that project,
I pull these changes, and my local changes goes into stash.
After that pull, when I try to recover my local changes from stash, it show me a error saying

```
"**unable to restore stash when changes are present on your branch github desktop"**
```

I do lot of changes in that project, that was equal to workload of 15 days.
I am not much familiar with git,

My question is about to recover stash files when github desktop is saying that you are unable to restore stash files.

Comment: Have a similar problem, their own issue (one of their devs) describes exactly that: Give more information/options to the user. Task Added to 2017, added to 2020, never heard of again. I was able to commit though, so just press commit, even though it creates a garbage commit, you can merge that with branch just like any other commit. (Make a backup first and don't kill me if this gets messed up anyways)